# Custom Newline in Binary Stream using Hex Array in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binary-search, binary-data

I have a binary file I am reading and printing into a textbox while wrapping at a set point, but it is wrapping at places it shouldn't be. I want to ignore all line feed characters except those I have defined.

There isn't a single Newline byte, rather it seems to be a series of them. I think I found the series of Hex values  `00-01-01-0B` that seem to correspond with where the line feeds should be.

How do I ignore existing line breaks, and use what I want instead?

This is where I am at:

```
shortFile = new FileStream(@"tempfile.dat", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
DisplayArea.Text = "";                
byte[] block = new byte[1000];
shortFile.Position = 0;
while (shortFile.Read(block, 0, 1000) > 0)
{
    string trimmedText =  System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(block);
    DisplayArea.Text += trimmedText + "\n";
}
```

Comment: You are putting random data into a textbox, you should not be surprised some of it is interpreted strangely. Perhaps you should filter the data to valid characters first? Or replace them with a filler character (block or dot)?

Comment: It seems likely that `block` is not `System.Text.Encoding.Default`.

Comment: NetMage, I am parsing old data files where I don't have much info on the format. To reconstruct what it should look like, I am not filtering out everything by default. @DourHighArch I am not sure what the error you are getting is, it is printing out just fine for me using that code.

Comment: what about omitting all bytes that are control codes - less than char(32) - do you want just printable characters in the textbox or also tabs etc.? your reader loop is cutting the input stream on arbitrary byte positions, so even if there was some multi-byte character encoding present, this would kill it.

Comment: That worked perfect @dlatikay. I was just coming to post that as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had just figured it out a couple minutes before dlatikay posted, but really appreciated seeing that he also had the right idea. I just replaced all control characters with spaces.

```
for (int i = 0; i < block.Length; i++)
{
    if (block[i] < 32)
    {
        block[i] = 0x20;
    }
}
```